# Trying to incorporate a selectInput and then an IF statemant into shinny app to display the updated value in a datatable

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, selectinput

I have been trying to get the if statement working so that I can convert the selectInputs into values that can be displayed into my DataTable but have not been able to achieve this. I tried by making it into a function that uses the selectInput to update it inside an eventreactive but had no luck since when the code is run my main panel goes blank (without displaying any errors). I tried using a function since this worked the first time I tried it with tasa_ftp. Can somebody help me with this?

````
# Define UI for FTP minimum
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Tasa Minima"),

    # Sidebar with a numeric and select inputs
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            numericInput("plazo",
                        label = "Plazo en Anos:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 10000,
                        value = 5),
            numericInput("tasa",
                        label = "Tasa Proyectada",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 10 ),
            selectInput(
              inputId = "banca",
              label = "Banca Correspondiente",
              choices =  c("Banca Juridica", "Banca Personas"),
              selected = "Banca Juridica",
              multiple = FALSE,
              selectize = FALSE,
              width = NULL,
              size = NULL
            ),
            
            actionButton(inputId = "input_action", label = "Mostrar Resultados")
        ),

        # Show a Data Table that updates through user inputs
        mainPanel(
          dataTableOutput("tasaminima")
        )
    )
)

# Functions

tasa_ftp_minima <- function(tasa,a){      
  C <- tasa/100
  y <- 0.0348
  m <- 365*a
  k <- m/a
  p <- 100
  df <- data.frame(t = seq(1,m,1),CF = C/k*p + c(rep.int(0,m-1),p))
  
  df$DF <- 1/(1+y/k)^(df$t)
  df$DC <- df$DF*df$CF
  
  P0 <- sum(df$DC)
  
  df$TDC <- df$t*df$DC
  
  STDC <- sum(df$TDC)
  
  dur <- STDC/P0
  a <- -0.000000001
  b <- 0.000009
  c <- 0.0311
  
  tasa_ftp <- signif((a*dur^2+b*dur+c)*100)
}

ctos_completos <- function(descripcion){
  if(descripcion == "Banca Juridica"){
    ctos <- as.numeric(0.0226)
    return(ctos)
    } else{
  if(descripcion == "Banca Personas"){
      ctos <- as.numeric(0.7057)
    return(ctos)
    }
  }
}

# Server

server <- function(input, output) {
  
tasa_ftp <- eventReactive(input$input_action,{
  tasa_ftp_minima(input$tasa,input$plazo)
})

ctos <- eventReactive(input$input_ction,{
    ctos_completos(as.character(input$banca))
  })


pe <- 3.5

output$tasaminima <- renderDataTable({
data.frame(Componentes = c("Tasa FTP", "Perdida Esperada", "ABC Costing","Tasa FTP Minima"),
           Resultado = c(tasa_ftp(),pe,ctos(),round(tasa_ftp()+pe+ctos(),2)))
    })
  
}




# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server) ```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is easier to spot an error when the code is reproducible, which means here you should include a sample dataset (and maybe instructions)  to run your app.

Comment: you have a typo in your code, check line `ctos <- eventReactive(input$input_ction,`

Comment: Thank you @HubertL some fresh eyes is what I needed. Happy to know that my logic was not wrong. But indeed correcting this typo solved the problem.